# listreceivedbyaddress returns empty list

Tags: address, api, payment

I tried `bitcoind getnewaddress`, but `bitcoind listreceivedbyaddress` still returned empty list

How to create a new address for receiving payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is to only return addresses that have already received coins, so use `bitcoind listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`.  The `true` indicates that you want to include "empty" addresses.

Source: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list