# Import watch-only address to 0.18 core wallet, addresses missing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, importaddress

I am running new bitcond server

```
$bitcoin-cli importaddress '32om7Xx7GnwxkiAQjpp3hhayDX4mSNLmR1' 'label' false
$
```

it seems added.

Then I try to list all addresses in wallet it return empty list.

```
$bitcoin-cli listaddressgroupings
[
]
```

here my bitcoind.conf

```
server=1
rpcuser=uname
rpcpassword=pass
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=18332
daemon=1
addresstype=p2sh-segwit

$ bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
  ""
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using on incorrect bitcoin-cli method to list your addresses.

The command you're looking for is:

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
```

The `0` parameter means you're requesting information on any address and the [`true` flag means you want empty addresses included](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/listreceivedbyaddress-returns-empty-list).

The original command you were attempting, `listaddressgroupings`, is described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25473/what-does-the-listaddressgroupings-rpc-method-do).